# How to set Prime NG radio button default value in reactive forms

Tags: angular, primeng

Below is my code where I need to pass a default value to a radio button.

```html
<div class="ui-g-12">
  <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 1" label="Option 1" [(ngModel)]="val1" inputId="opt1"></p-radioButton>
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12">
  <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 2" label="Option 2" [(ngModel)]="val1" inputId="opt2"></p-radioButton>
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12">
  <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 3" label="Option 3" [(ngModel)]="val1" inputId="opt3"></p-radioButton>
</div>
```

Can anyone please explain how to set the default value to a radio button when the form loads?

Comment: whichever button has the value that matches what `val1` is set to will be the default. So set `val1` to e.g. `'Option 1'` to select that button.

Comment: This isn't a reactive form, so set the default value like suggested by match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First change the way you build your form to the `ReactiveForms` way:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <div class="ui-g-12">
   <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 1" label="Option 1" formControlName="myRadio" inputId="opt1"></p-radioButton>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-g-12">
   <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 2" label="Option 2" formControlName="myRadio"  inputId="opt2"></p-radioButton>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-g-12">
   <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 3" label="Option 3"  formControlName="myRadio"  inputId="opt3"></p-radioButton>
 </div>
</form>
```

And in the component set the default value when you initialize it:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  myForm;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      myRadio: ['Option 1', []] // This set default value
    })
  }
}
```

Runing example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fu81jc

Primeng docs: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/radiobutton

ReactiveForms docs: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Stackblitz works, but it isn't working in my code. Why can't primeNg just have `[checked]`? My code is near identical to the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me: create a var using the ngModel name and set that to the value attribute from the template. here  I set ngModel to 'itsYourNgModel' and value to 'thisRightHere', then use those attr. vals in the typescript file.
Template:

```
<p-radioButton
  [(ngModel)]="itsYourNgModel"
  value="thisRightHere"
  inputId="aCleverName"
  name="aCleverName"
  label="Melt my PC"
  binary="true"
  (onClick)="getFire()"
></p-radioButton>
<p-radioButton>
[...]
</p-radioButton>
```

typescript:

```
itsYourNgModel = 'thisRightHere';
```

Why does it work? Ask primeNG 'cos idk.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ruben , for the boolean types in Primeng you can use [value] = true in p-radioButton.